# searching for a variable value using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file containing the following data :

```
[abc]

p=xyz

q=123

r=nm

[stu]

p=hjk

q=1234

r=jk
```

I want to access the value of variable "p" which is inside the block"abc".

Can anybody help me in this?
Thanks

Comment: try to indicate if answers help to you by commenting and, eventually, accepting them.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start checking lines once `[abc]` is found and stop once another line starting with `[` is found. In the meanwhile, check the first field being `p` and, in that case, print the second one:

```
$ awk -F= '$1=="[abc]" {f=1; next} f && $1=="p" {print $2} f && /^\[/ {f=0}' file
xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="["} $1=="abc]"{ print $2 }' <filename> | cut -d'=' -f2
```

This will give the value of p, i.e. xyz.